# Custom home tile/icon for web bookmarks on the Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, tile

Is it possible to set a custom home tile/icon for web bookmarks on the Windows Phone 7? Currently, when you select "pin to start" on a web page, the resulting home page tile is just a screen shot. Is there a way to make it a custom icon (like you can on the iPhone)?

Answer (score 4):

Nope. You can't alter the screenshot image.
At least not yet. Who knows what may come in future updates.

Answer (score 1):

There is a work-around for this.  You create an image that overlays the entire site and prompt the user to "pin this site".  It is a little hack-y, but seems to work on WP7 & 8 
http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/19/creating-a-custom-tile-to-link-to-your-website.aspx

Here is a working example I put together:
http://cdpn.io/jlEur

Comment: I dont see how this is useful. Every time user has to dismiss this overlay.

Comment: The implementation of whether you display the overlay is dependent on the design you want to use.  If you add a more obvious persistent triggering element (like the example), then yes users would have to dismiss it (although you should remember this with a cookie so they don't see it again).  As an option, you could just use a styled anchor that isn't so obnoxious.

Answer (score 0):

Just found an online tool you can use directly with your Windows Phone browser if you don't mind getting redirected:

http://cheller.info/wpt/

Source code for it:
https://github.com/fedecheller/WPCustomWebTiles

Found here in the Phone Developer Blog, look for "fedecheller". 
http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/10/19/creating-a-custom-tile-to-link-to-your-website.aspx

It's not the best solution, it would be nicer if you could simply edit the icon on the phone..
And you can: Check the Windows Phone Marketplace for a tool called "Wiztiles".

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Phone 8-10 your can do it easily using the *browserconfig.xml* file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
  <msapplication>
    <tile>
      <square70x70logo src="images/smalltile.png"/>
      <square150x150logo src="images/mediumtile.png"/>
      <wide310x150logo src="images/widetile.png"/>
      <square310x310logo src="images/largetile.png"/>
      <TileColor>#009900</TileColor>
    </tile>
  </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

And in the HTML file

```
<head>
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="browserconfig.xml" />
</head>
```

More infos [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn455106.aspx)